# how much NodeMCU GPIO Current Maximum, and NodeMCU standalone Power Consumption?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

Unfortunately, i can't find hardware Spec about NodeMCU.

so i want know about GPIO Current limitation, Standalone Power Comsumptionm, and board size.

or Can you share the link about NodeMCU Hardware Spec?

some page say that GPIO Current Maximum is 12mA, but I can't find any Confidently say.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [datasheet (i.e. "Technical Reference")](https://espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp8266-technical_reference_en.pdf) doesn't say but an Espressif employee answered [that question in their forums](http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=139):

> 1. 12mA here refers to the source current and sink current is greater than 12mA.
> 2. 12mA is for per pin and each pin is the same.
> 3. Drive capacity current of all GPIO pins total can be 16 x 12 mA.

And

> The sink current of GPIO is about 20mA. The maximum source current of
> GPIO is about 12mA.

Answer (score 3):

An small point to add, ESP8266 power consumption is easy to find in the spec ( e.g. http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=esp8266_power_usage ), but its not really NodeMCU. The USB UART, LDO, LED on NodeMCU all draw constant power, if you want to e.g. run on battery power( https://tinker.yeoman.com.au/2016/05/29/running-nodemcu-on-a-battery-esp8266-low-power-consumption-revisited/ ) this has to be considered.

From the above link:

> I measured ***18mA*** to the NodeMCU board while the ESP8266 was in ***deep*** sleep mode – orders of magnitude more power hungry than I was looking for..
>
> Now for the biggest saving – to disable the USB UART. ...
>
> You will now have reduced power consumption by some 360x to around 50μA 20μA [Updated 28 Jan 2017 when I was powering only the NodeMCU, without additional circuitry]. ...

Comment: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._